# Iterating through an array and play sound issue

Tags: c#

I am traversing an array list of Music Notes object with the aim to play a whole stream of sound files all of each with a different duration.
The problem is that I can hear only just like a beep for each music note!!

The thread is going sleep for the length of the current MusicNote so I don't know why I am hearing only beeps!

```
//----------Play the whole list----------
public void PlayAll()
{
    foreach (MusicNote m in list)
    {
        m.sp1.Stop();
        m.sp1.Play();
        Thread.Sleep(m.NoteDuration * 100);
    }
}
```

Comment: mind to share what `sp1` is?

Comment: you can use Console.Beep(frequency, duration) and it be better if you share MusicNote

Comment: It is an instance of Sound Player

Answer (score 0):

Your posted code should work.You will just call that function on thread. if console there is no need for thread too

And here is  your problem :

> If the .wav file has not been specified or it fails to load, the Play
> method will play the default beep sound.

[SoundPlayer.Play documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.media.soundplayer.play%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)